# Why doesn't the textfield code work for Xcode 8 Obj-C?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xcode8, textfield

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextField *Signup;
IBOutlet UITextField *Login;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *Signup;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *Login;

-(IBAction)TYPE:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
@synthesize Signup;
@synthesize Login;

-(IBAction)TYPE:(id)sender{
[Signup resignFirstResponder];
[Login resignFirstResponder];
}
```

In Simulator when I click on the textfield I get the following error message:

2017-04-14 18:43:52.616362 Prototype1[3075:119579] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/robertstoley/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/09556F3B-A7BC-4DF2-95EB-C3C13B6F39EA/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
 2017-04-14 18:43:52.640402 Prototype1[3075:119579] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
 2017-04-14 18:43:52.727 Prototype1[3075:119579] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1316927560_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
 2017-04-14 18:43:53.607676 Prototype1[3075:119579] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7403; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
 2017-04-14 18:43:53.608246 Prototype1[3075:119579] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7403; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"

I haven't used Xcode in 2 years, but this same code worked fine then, why doesn't it work for Xcode 8, iOS 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator for Xcode 8 is quite verbose. Those messages don't mean anything special.

-- BTW --

Your code is written in a *very* old style that isn't best practice anymore. Better is:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
// It's no longer necessary to have your properties between { and }

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *signup;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *login;
// IBOutlets should be weak, other properties should be weak or strong for objects, or assign for structs and values.
@end


@implementation ViewController

// You don't have to synthesize your properties anymore.

- (IBAction)type:(id)sender {
    [self.signup resignFirstResponder];
    [_login resignFirstResponder];
    // but you do have to either use self. or underscore to refer to them.
}

@end
```

Comment: The keyboard doesn't show up at all. How do I get the keyboard to show up?

Comment: Ah, that has to do with your xib file or storyboard. Given how old your code looks, I'm guessing you are dealing with xib files.

Comment: I'm using storyboard. What's the issue? How do I fix it? I haven't coded in 2 years. I just got back to it, if that helps.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your storyboard. The right panel for each text field.

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out already. You were right. It's a storyboard issue. I have to turn on simulator > Hardware > Toggle Software. Then the keyboard started working as normal.